# Preloading same resource in 2 different HTML pages

Tags: html, css, performance, preload

I have 2 separate HTML files, one just serving the homepage and another one serving the other routes of the application.

There is a CSS file, let's say common.css, which is needed for both the HTMLs.

If I have preloaded like,

```
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="/css/common.css" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" />
```

In home page HTML, will it still be available in HTTP cache for my other routes navigation? Or do I have to preload common.css again in second HTML file.

I am new to using resource hints..

Answer (score 0):

If preload is essential for both the renderings use preload twice. If the stylesheet is already loaded in the browsercache the browser will use it. If the stylesheet for one reason or the other is flushed it will preload it again. The most important thing is that you use the same path for both the calls.

Oh, and do not forget to tell the browser to store your sheet e.g. in apache or via the meta tag.

You could try to make a few test pages and look at the behaviour of the browser cache.